# Text in <p> tag overflowing off left side of screen on mobile

Tags: css, mobile, text, screen, paragraph

I'm trying to get this site working for mobile devices: http://whitehallrow.com/

The text body under the slideshow is working fine on my Blackberry, but all the paragraphs under the blue ribbons are running off the left side of the screen. I've tried many different things with CSS, such as margins, padding, width:100%, float, text-align - and nothing has even changed it slightly.

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the width entirely from this code (I think its around line 340 in your CSS)

```
.homeblurb {
   width: 480px; /* <- remove this value */
   float: right;
   padding-right: 16px;
}
```

Comment: I took away all the styling from .homeblurb, but it's still running off the screen. I'm using a Blackberry Bold 9700.

Comment: Hmm... I've changed the CSS in my custom CSS plugin, but when I inspect the element on the page, it still has all the old styling... so apparently there's something wrong with the plugin.

Comment: Are you using a CSS Reset of some description that might be overriding your style?

Comment: I just found the problem, I had cut and pasted the code for the home page to the top of my CSS sheet for ease of editing, but the plugin messed up and copied it instead, which has happened before... so the code farther down was overriding my changes. My bad. Thanks anyway for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Because you have a fixed `width: 480px` on that `p`, and there is a padding-right, so the text runs off the screen. Try not to set the width at all, I tested in chrome and it works.